# What is implications of well ordering theorem regarding order in nature?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, natural-philosophy

I have recently come across well-ordering theorem.

And I found that well-ordering theorem is equivalent to axiom of choice.

And as far I know, axiom of choice is what we understand as free will, that isn't necessarily to have any algorithm to determine nor it is random, which is what we understand by choice.

So my question is,

How does well ordering theorem related to order in nature if there any order at all?

What does well ordering theorem shows about choice?

If we found something in universe that is orderly independent of humans, can well ordering theorem be used to conclude necessary existence of choice?

And is theorem can be used to prove God who makes choice necessary for order?

Comment: Just because two words share a root does not mean that their referents are related. The concept of ["order"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_theory) in mathematics is technical and narrow (even so, it is broader than just well ordering). And even within mathematics there are other concepts more closely related to "order in nature" than order, such as structure and symmetry.

Answer (score 2):

Axiom of choice has nothing to do with free will and the well-ordering theorem has almost nothing to do with order in nature.  They just have similar names.

The axiom of choice says that the Cartesian product of an indexed set of non-empty sets is non-empty.   There isn't really any "choice" in the psychological sense involved.

The well-ordering theorem says that every set can be equipped with a less-than relationship "<" satisfying certain axioms, such that every subset of the set has a least element under "<".  This represents a specific kind of order, but order in nature is a far more broad concept; e.g. a bridge across a river is ordered, in a way that has virtually nothing to do with the well-ordering theorem.